# SQL select distinct rows

Tags: sql

I have data like this (col2 is of type Date)

```
| col1 |        col2         |
------------------------------
|  1   | 17/10/2007 07:19:07 |
|  1   | 17/10/2007 07:18:56 |
|  1   | 31/12/2070          |
|  2   | 28/11/2008 15:23:14 |
|  2   | 31/12/2070          |
```

How would select rows which col1 is distinct and the value of col2 is the greatest. Like this

```
| col1 |        col2         |
------------------------------
|  1   | 31/12/2070          |
|  2   | 31/12/2070          |
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

```
SELECT col1, MAX(col2) FROM some_table GROUP BY col1;
```

Answer (score 4):

```
 select col1, max(col2)
 from table
 group by col1
```

Answer (score 3):

i reckon it would be

select col1, max(col2)
from DemoTable
group by col1

unless i've missed something obvious

Answer (score 3):

```
select col1, max(col2) from MyTable
group by col1
```

Answer (score 2):

SELECT Col1, MAX(Col2) FROM YourTable GROUP BY Col1

Answer (score 0):

In `Oracle` and `MS SQL`:

```
SELECT  *
FROM    (
        SELECT  t.*, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY col1 ORDER BY col2 DESC) rn
        FROM    table t
        ) q
WHERE rn = 1
```

This will select other columns along with `col1` and `col2`

Comment: I think you mean "select other columns .."